# Spinner, not set value if i dont click(android)

Tags: android, android-layout, spinner

I have a spinner:

```
 spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int childposition, long id) {
        textView.setText(spinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        textView.setText("");
    }
    });
```

Above you'll see that **textView** - is my text object. I'm displaying a text item spinner in the textView when I click it. If I dont click the spinner then my **textView** must be `textView.setText("");`

But the spinner is always set text in my **textView**, even if I do not choose spinner.

### Question

How can I accomplish this?:

- If I dont choose item spinner, textView is empty: `textView.setText("");`
- If I do choose the item spinner, textView gets: `textView.setText(spinner.getSelectedItem().toString());`

Comment: I tried my best to understand the problem. I assisted with wording and clarified the question.

Comment: Surely this is just a case of giving focus to another element? How are you 'showing' the spinner after the click? Creating manually, or making a previously hidden/invisible element, visible? You're missing some key information here.

Answer (score 1):

```
String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(childposition).toString(); //Get selected item

if(item.equals("spinner")){ // Check if it equals spinner

     textView.setText(item); // Set text to item

}else{

     textView.setText(""); // If it doesn't equal spinner set text to ""

}
```

If I understood the question right, putting this instead of `textView.setText(spinner.getSelectedItem().toString());` and deleting content of onNothingSelected should do the trick.

**UPDATE**

I finally understood what you mean. To do this create your spinner like this and add "" as first choice in your string-array resource :

```
String[] newArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.yourArray);
List<String> myResArrayList = Arrays.asList(newArray);
ArrayList<String> spinnerItems = new ArrayList<String>(myResArrayList);

//Making adapter with ArrayList instead of String[] allows us to add/remove items later in the code

Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
// Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, spinnerItems);
// Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
// Apply the adapter to the spinner
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

spinnerItems.remove(0);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // Here we remove the first choice which is "" so the user won't be able to select empty.
```

Comment: Thanks for unswer. No, you did not understand me. I have a spinner, I have to do so -> if I not clicked on spinner `textView.setText("");`

Comment: You mean if you open the spinner options and then close without choosing to setText("") ? Also do you have android:text="..." on the TextView in your xml - if so remove it.

Comment: In standart spinner set text `textView` when the program starts. I dont want this. I want set text `textView` when i click spinner